# Trouble with function in the for-loop

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, function

```
def vol_tank(R,h):
    ht = R + 2.3*R

    if ht >= h:
        vol = 3.14 * R*R * h + 3.14 * R*R * h / 3
        print ('R: %.1f , h: %.1f - volume: %.2f' % (R,h,vol))
    elif R >= h:
        vol = 3.14 * R*R * h / 3
        print ('R: %.1f , h: %.1f - volume: %.2f' % (R,h,vol))
    else:
        print ('R: %.1f , h: %.1f - overflowing' % (R,h))

values = [[0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5], [1, 1.25, 3.8, 4.5]]
table = [[vol_tank(R,h) for R in values[0]] for h in values[1]]
```

->Table is making the calculation of all numbers from the first list of 'values' with all the numbers from the second list (ex: 0.8 with 1, 0.8 with 1.25, 0.8 with 3.8 and so on...).

But what I wanted was only with their respective pairs, like this: 0.8 with 1, 1 with 1.25, 1.3 with 3.8 and 1.5 with 4.5.

Comment: if you control the input why are they in two separate lists , why  not in pairs? Your table list will be full of None's also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `zip()` function then:

```
table = [vol_tank(R, h) for R, h in zip(*values)]
```

And you should return the result from `vol_tank()` instead of just printing, otherwise `table` will be a list full of `None` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define values as a list of pairs from the start:

```
values = [(0.8, 1) (1, 1.25), (1.3, 3.8), (1.5, 4.5)]
```

Or use the `zip` function:

```
values = [[0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5], [1, 1.25, 3.8, 4.5]]
table = [vol_tank(R,h) for R, h in zip(values[0], values[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is building a so called cross product, which combines each value from the first list with each value in the second list. What you want is to pair the values, which is the same as picking always the next value from each list and putting those values together. Then pic the next values and so on. As this is a quite common problem, it's already available in python. It's the zip function. Here's an example how to use it and how the output looks like:

```
In [1]: values = [[0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5], [1, 1.25, 3.8, 4.5]]
In [2]: zip(*values)
Out[2]: [(0.8, 1), (1, 1.25), (1.3, 3.8), (1.5, 4.5)]
```

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Nested list comprehensions are just like nested loops, for every instance of h in your outer comprehension, every instance of R in your inner comprehension is executed/evaluated. Four in each list, means 16 results (4 x 4), instead, either recast your values list as a list of tuples and loop over the tuples with implicit unpacking

```
values = [(0.8, 1), (1, 1.25), (1.3, 3.8), (1.5, 4.5)]
table = [vol_tank(R,h) for R, h in values]
```

Or loop an integer index over the length of the lists (which must be the same), as in

```
values = [[0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5], [1, 1.25, 3.8, 4.5]]
table = [vol_tank(values[0][i],values[1][i]) for i in range(len(values[0]))]
```